# Did Prezi really switch to JS + Canvas?

Tags: prezi

I've [read](https://medium.com/prezi-engineering/how-and-why-prezi-turned-to-javascript-56e0ca57d135) that Prezi reimplemented their presentation player in Javascript using `<canvas>` after using the Flash-based one for years.

However if I open any prezi in my browser, such as [this one](https://prezi.com/kltb-0eyq1pm/fathom-vip-series-presenting-on-presenting), I still get a Flash presentation (if I right-click the presentation controls or screen, the last entry in the context menu is *About Adobe Flash Player...*)

Why is that? I really want to try the JS version, how can I do that?

Comment: Turn off flash.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh That only gives me a big red message saying _Prezi needs Flash Player 11.1 or better. Upgrade [here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer)._

Comment: Several months later, access to that feature is still hidden somewhere....